# create another function for deprecated name

Tags: dart

```
class PubTools {
  void update(Context context, {bool force: false}) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

is Old code. and I'd like to change function name `update` to `upgrade`.

> ```
> class PubTools {
>   @deprecated
>   void update(Context context, {bool force: false}) {
>     upgrade(context, force);
>   }
>   void upgrade(Context context, {bool force: false}) {
>     // do something
>   }
> }
> ```

But `dartanalyzer` returns warning.

something like..

[warning] 1 positional arguments expected, but 2 found (/home/sungguk/program_store/lib/grinder
_utils.dart, line 130, col 8)

How can I remove warning? what's correct grammer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The {...} syntax denotes [named parameters](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#functions-optional-parameters).

You must call the method by passing the name of the named parameter:

```
upgrade(context, force: force);
```

By not calling it with the parameter name it is treated as a positional parameter, but there is only one positional parameter expected for the upgrade method so it results in a warning.